# function to check required form fields not working

Tags: php, forms

I have a user defined function, it takes one argument as an array for the form required fields. It checks if these fields are empty or not. If they are empty it will return a message and stop processing the form.

```
<?php

function check_required_fields($required_array) {
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0)) { 

        }
    }
    return "You have errors";
}
$required_array = array('name', 'age');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo check_required_fields($required_array);
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The function is returning this error even when the form required fields are filled? how to fix this?
How can i use just use the function with out writing the word echo before its name?

I want to use this function so i don't have to manually write the if and else statement for every field in the form.

Comment: the return needs to be inside the if clause

Comment: you can just use `if(empty($fieldname)) return false;` , the other control are unuseful, and i would pass the $_POST to the function directly `check_required_fields($_POST)`

Comment: I want to show customized errors of the empty fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do like this?

```
function check_required_fields($required_array) {
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0)) { 
            return "You have errors"; //This indicates that there are errors
        }
    }
}
```

or why not just:

```
function check_required_fields($required_array) {
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname])) { 
            return "You have errors"; //This indicates that there are errors
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Change:

```
$required_array = array('name', 'age'); //This just sets strings name and age into the array
```

to:

```
$required_array = array($_POST['name'], $_POST['age']); //This takes the values from the form
```

Comment: I tried the second suggested code and it didn't output any error message? I fully understand you change and suggestion to the code. but  it is not working.

Comment: It works. how can i return the empty $fieldname one on each line? example: return $fieldname . "is required <br >"; i tried this it is not working.